# Recursively patching the properties of an ORM model and related models

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following excerpt is part of a method for recursively patching the properties of an ORM model and related models using a dictionary:

```
try:
    anhaenge = d['anhaenge']
except KeyError:
    self.logger.debug('anhaenge unchanged')
else:
    try:
        anhang = anhaenge['anhang']
    except KeyError:
        self.logger.debug('anhaenge.anhang unchanged')
    except TypeError:  # anhaenge is probably None
        for record in self.anhang:
            yield (record, PatchMode.DELETE)
    else:
        for record in self.anhang:
            yield (record, PatchMode.DELETE)

        if anhang:
            for anhang_ in anhang:
                with suppress(EmptyDict):
                    for record in Anhang.from_dict(
                            anhang_, immobilie=self):
                        yield (record, PatchMode.CREATE)
```

I currently violate the *don't repeat yourself* (DRY) principle, since I do the very same operation within the block handling the `TypeError` and at the beginning of the inner `else` block.
How can I resolve this to have the code

```
for record in self.anhang:
    yield (record, PatchMode.DELETE)
```

only once?

**Clarifying the input**:

The input`d` is a dictionary derived by `json.loads()` from a JSON string through a web API.
The method, the above excerpt is extracted from uses this dictionary to modify database records represented by the ORM model this methods belongs to.
Examples of `d`:

```
# Delete all subsequent anhang records
d = {'anhaenge': {
    'anhang': None}}

# Change all related anhang records to those represented by the dicts in
# the list, meaning:
# 1) Delete all old records
# 2) Create new ones from the dicts
d = {'anhaenge': {
    'anhang': [
        {'anhangtitel': 'Attachment1'},
        {'anhangtitel': 'Attachment2'}]}}

# All subsequent anhang records are left as they are.
# Subsequent foo records may be altered accordingly
d = {'anhaenge': {
    'foo': 'bar'}}
```

Comment: With the addition of clarifying the input, how should `{'anhaenge': None}` work?

Comment: Remove this ```anhaenge``` record and all its related records (contains also other amongst ```anhang```). This is essentially the reason for the ```TypeError``` block.

Comment: So the `TypeError` block does more than what you show here?

Comment: No. Within the outer ```else``` block, below the inner ```try... except... else...``` there come further ```try... except... else...``` blocks similar to this one for other sub-keys of ```anhaenge```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that either `for` loop can come before or after the other `for` loop.
Then you should check if `anhaenge is not None`.
As your `except TypeError` is to guard against that.
You can then `return` from the function after you log the error, remove the `except TypeError`, remove the duplicate `for` loop,
and finally, put the duplicate `for` loop after the `if`, as you wish to perform the loop here on either branch. EG:

```
try:
    anhaenge = d['anhaenge']
except KeyError:
    self.logger.debug('anhaenge unchanged')
else:
    if anhaenge is not None:
        try:
            anhang = anhaenge['anhang']:
        except KeyError:
            self.logger.debug('anhaenge.anhang unchanged')
            return
        else:
            for anhang_ in anhang:
                with suppress(EmptyDict):
                    for record in Anhang.from_dict(anhang_, immobilie=self):
                        yield record, PatchMode.CREATE
    for record in self.anhang:
        yield (record, PatchMode.DELETE)
```

But this is not possible if the duplicated `for` loop has to occur before the other `for` loop.

Either way, I honestly don't think you're input is right.
Your input is strange, `None` is normally used to say it's not there, and so `dict.get('a', None)` is a common occurrence.
However your code performs differently whether it's `None` or not there.
And so I'd say you should restructure the input so you can use say:

```
anhang = d.get('anhaenge', {}).get('anhang', None)
if anhang:
    for record in self.anhang:
        yield (record, PatchMode.DELETE)

    for anhang_ in anhang:
        with suppress(EmptyDict):
            for record in Anhang.from_dict(
                    anhang_, immobilie=self):
                yield (record, PatchMode.CREATE)
else:
    self.logger.debug('anhaenge or anhaenge.anhang is unchanged')
```

---

If you can't adapt either of the above, then I'd say your code is good for your situation.

Comment: "But this is not possible if the duplicated for loop has to occur before the other for loop." - Which is exactly the case. 
Regarding the ```None``` - this indicates, that the subsequent content schould be deleted, while the absence of the key indicates that the subsequent content should not be changed at all.

Comment: @RichardNeumann And so I'd point you to my final paragraph. And repeat your input is odd.

Comment: So how'd you suggest I'd do differ whether a field should be changed, deleted/nullified or not being touched?

Comment: @RichardNeumann I don't know that much about your other code, but you can pass an argument or add a flag in the dictionary, which says to delete the current `self.anhang`. And return the delete tuples if it's true.

Comment: I understand, that the details of this problem do not become quite clear through this example. Maybe this would be a different question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I wouldn't post this question as it is on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I meant the question about trinary states of dict keys...

Comment: @RichardNeumann You could try Software Engineering, but be sure to check their [help centre](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to delete old records if `d['anhaenge']['anhang']` is present, whatever its value. And if it is not `None`, you want to update with new values as well.

The catch being that `d` may not contain the `'anhaenge'` key, or the value for that key may be `None`. Looking at the `except TypeError`, the behaviour seems to be the same if you have `d = {'anhaenge': None}` and `d = {'anhaenge': {'anhang': None}}`. But `d` not containing `'anhaenge'` should do nothing.

Since you say it's part of a method, you may extract a behaviour into its own function to benefit from early return: get a dictionnary of new values for `'anhang'`, or `None` if it shouldn't be changed:

```
def extract_anhang(d):
    try:
        anhaenge = d['anhaenge']
    except KeyError:
        self.logger.debug('anhaenge unchanged')
        return

    if anhaenge is None:
        return {}

    try:
        anhang = anhaenge['anhang']
    except KeyError:
        self.logger.debug('anhaenge.anhang unchanged')
        return
    return {} if anhang is None else anhang
```

and then, you can simplify your method into:

```
anhang = extract_anhang(d)
if anhang is not None:
    for record in self.anhang:
        yield (record, PatchMode.DELETE)

    for anhang_ in anhang:
        with suppress(EmptyDict):
            for record in Anhang.from_dict(anhang_, immobilie=self):
                yield (record, PatchMode.CREATE)
```

---

You can also use the same function to handle other subkeys similarly. Just parametrize it by the name of the subkey:

```
def extract_subkey(container, primarykey, subkey):
    try:
        subcontainer = container[primarykey]
    except KeyError:
        self.logger.debug('%s unchanged', primarykey)
        return

    if subcontainer is None:
        return {}

    try:
        subvalue = subcontainer[subkey]
    except KeyError:
        self.logger.debug('%s.%s unchanged', primarykey, subkey)
        return
    return {} if subvalue is None else subvalue
```

And the call become

```
anhang = extract_subkey(d, 'anhaenge', 'anhang')
```

---

In case you really prefer the `TypeError` approach (but I wouldn't use it as your comment suggest it is "probably" not the right approach), you can still use it instead of that `if`:

```
def extract_subkey(container, primarykey, subkey):
    try:
        subcontainer = container[primarykey]
    except KeyError:
        self.logger.debug('%s unchanged', primarykey)
        return

    try:
        subvalue = subcontainer[subkey]
    except TypeError:
        # subcontainer is probably None
        return {}
    except KeyError:
        self.logger.debug('%s.%s unchanged', primarykey, subkey)
        return
    return {} if subvalue is None else subvalue
```

In the end, nothing much changes, as this versions provide the same flow than yours, but early returns makes it more readable. You still have your two repeated blocks of code but they are now `return {}` and, even though they are linked to the logic, they don't contain some on their own; so it's better for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to keep your logging you can use something like this.

```
anhaenge = d.get('anhaenge')

if anhaenge is None:
    self.logger.debug('anhaenge unchanged')
    return

anhang = anhaenge.get('anhang')
if anhang is None:
    self.logger.debug('anhaenge.anhang unchanged')
    return

for record in self.anhang:
    yield (record, PatchMode.DELETE)

for anhang_ in anhang:
    with suppress(EmptyDict):
        for record in Anhang.from_dict(
                anhang_, immobilie=self):
            yield (record, PatchMode.CREATE)
```

Comment: I currently differ between the absence of a key and it having a ```None``` value, beacuse it has a different meaning. See my comment on @Peilonrayz answer for details.